# domains redirect using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a website with an domain www.site1.com/ then this website also has addresses that has a domain that looks like this blog.site1.com/.

So its : www.site1.com/ and blog.site1.com/

So both is the same website (site1) how can i redirect both of them to the same site - site2.com?

Currently the www.site1.com is easily redirecting using this method:

```
  RedirectMatch 301 ^/en-us/location.htm http://site2.com/contact/

  RedirectMatch 301 ^/en-us/sitemap.htm http://site2.com/-estates/the-pet-room/

  RedirectMatch 301 ^/ http://site2.com/

  RedirectMatch 301 ^/en-us/ http://site2.com/
```

So this redirects the page itself and the individual pages for www.site1 now in this same .htaccess file can i redirect blog.site1.com ? hope its clear enough.

Comment: Is your subdomain pointing blog folder?

Comment: No , its not. The sub domain actually does not exist anymore but for SEO purposes needs to redirect to my new site.